# What would be the parameters for a services to receive a JSON file?

Tags: services

This might be sound like a very foolish question ...

I want to expose a service to receive a JSON file from client side in GET or POST format through which I can send an email. What should be my initial algorithm?

I know I need to implement `hook_services_resources()` to create a resource for the services.

But I don't get what would be its parameters and what would be there in resource api [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drupal_json_output($resultsarray);
```

you will get json data